# Improving performance of Redis set up (degraded after setting vm.overcommit_memory=1)

Tags: redis, linux-kernel

Need some help in diagnosing and tuning the performance of my Redis set up (2 redis-server instances on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine). Note that a write-heavy Django web application shares the VM with Redis. The machine has 8 cores and 25GB RAM.

I recently discovered that background saving was intermittently failing (with a `fork()` error) even when RAM wasn't exhausted. To remedy this, I applied the setting `vm.overcommit_memory=1` (was previously `default`).

Moreover `vm.swappiness=2`, `vm.overcommit_ratio=50`. I have disabled transparent huge pages in my set up as well via `echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` (although **haven't** done `echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag`).

Right after changing the `overcommit_memory` setting, I noticed that I/O utilization went from 13% to 36% (on average). I/O operations per second doubled, the redis-server CPU consumption has more than doubled, and the memory it's consuming has gone up 66%. Consequently, the server response time has substantially gone up . This is how abruptly things escalated after applying `vm.overcommit_memory=1`:

[image]

Note that redis-server is the only ingredient showing escalation - gunicorn, nginx ,celery etc. are performing like before. Moreover, redis has become very spikey.

[image]

Lastly, New Relic has started showing me 3 redis instances instead of 2 (bottom most graph). I think the forked child is counted as the 3rd:

[image]

**My question is:** how can I diagnose and salvage performance here? Being new to server administration, I'm unsure how to proceed. Help me find out what's going on here and how I can fix it.

---

`free -m` has the following output (in case needed):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         28136      27912        224        576         68       6778
-/+ buffers/cache:      21064       7071
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you don't have swap enabled in your system ( which might be worth reconsidering if you have SSDs), ( and your `swappiness` was set to a low value), you can't blame it on increased swapping due to memory contention.

Your caching about 6GB of data inside the VFS cache. In case of contention this cache would have depleted in favor of process working memory, so I believe it's safe to say memory is not an issue all together.

It's a shot in the dark, but my guess is that your redis-server is configured to "sync"/"save" too often ( search for in the redis config file "appendfsync"), and that by removing the memory allocation limitation, it now actually does it's job :)

If the data is not super crucial, set `appendfsync` to `never` and perhaps tweek the `save` settings to cause less frequent saving.

BTW, regarding the redis & forked child, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Spot on. The rdb of my two redis-servers is ~1GB and ~4GB respectively, and the save settings were having them save every 60s. Changed to 5m and 20m respectively. Might increase even more. Btw, my `vm.overcommit_ratio` is set at 50. I've read that that's low; it should be at least 100. What would you suggest? Or does it not matter?

Comment: I wouldn't tinker with the overcommit settings unless necessary. 
If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: Yep accepted! Thanks for the help Sheinbergon. I've been wondering why changing `vm.overcommit_memory=1` would have triggered the problem, since my `save` settings were pretty aggressive beforehand as well. Do you suppose the `fork()` was failing previously? Or something else? Just trying to understand what I've been going through :-)

Comment: Overcommit memory basically allows a process to allocate more virtual memory than actually available on the system. Virtual memory is not real, it's just a "wild" number, meant to satisfy allocation request needs. In times of contention, either swapping will take place or the allocation will fail.

By allowing your process to overcommit, the fork stopped fail and the `save` op could actually take place